# Creating IPN URL for PayPal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have PayPal setup using the paypal recurring gem. I need help understanding how to implement PayPal IPN.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is the last step for my project. I need to have the IPN setup so that when users cancel/suspend billing from their PayPal account that it will show as cancelled from my database.

Paypal_payment.rb:

```
   def initialize(subscription)
      @subscription = subscription
    end

    def checkout_details
      process :checkout_details
    end

    def checkout_url(options)
      process(:checkout, options).checkout_url
    end

    def make_recurring
      process :request_payment
      process :create_recurring_profile, period: :monthly, frequency: 1, start_at: Time.zone.now
    end

    def suspend
        process :suspend, :profile_id => @subscription.paypal_recurring_profile_token
    end

    def reactivate
        process :reactivate, :profile_id => @subscription.paypal_recurring_profile_token
    end

  private

    def process(action, options = {})
      options = options.reverse_merge(
        token: @subscription.paypal_payment_token,
        payer_id: @subscription.paypal_customer_token,
        description: @subscription.plan.name,
        amount: @subscription.plan.price,
        ipn_url: "http://mydomain.com/paypal/ipn",
        currency: "USD"
      )
      response = PayPal::Recurring.new(options).send(action)
      raise response.errors.inspect if response.errors.present?
      response
    end
  end
```

Subscription.rb:

```
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :subscription
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :plan_id
  validates_presence_of :email

  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token, :paypal_payment_token

  def expires_at
    self.updated_at + plan.duration.days
  end

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      if paypal_payment_token.present?
        save_with_paypal_payment
      else
        save_with_stripe_payment
      end
    end
  end

  def paypal
    PaypalPayment.new(self)
  end

  def save_with_paypal_payment
    response = paypal.make_recurring
    self.paypal_recurring_profile_token = response.profile_id
    save!
  end

  def save_with_stripe_payment
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
    self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
    save!
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
    false
  end

  def payment_provided?
    stripe_card_token.present? || paypal_payment_token.present?
  end

  def suspend_paypal
    paypal.suspend
    save
  end


  def reactivate_paypal
    paypal.reactivate
    save
  end

  def update_card(subscriber, card_info)
  token = Stripe::Token.create(
    card: {
      number: card_info[:number],
      exp_month: card_info[:exp_month],
      exp_year: card_info[:exp_year],
      cvc: card_info[:cvc]
    }
  )
  customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(user.subscription.stripe_customer_token)
  card = customer.cards.create(card: token.id)
  card.save
  customer.default_card = card.id
  customer.save
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while updating card info: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "#{e.message}"
    false
  end
end
```

Subscriptions controller:

```
  def new
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
    if params[:PayerID]
      @subscription.paypal_customer_token = params[:PayerID]
      @subscription.paypal_payment_token = params[:token]
      @subscription.email = @subscription.paypal.checkout_details.email
    end
  end

  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])
    if @subscription.save_with_payment
      redirect_to @subscription, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end

  def paypal_checkout
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
    redirect_to subscription.paypal.checkout_url(
      return_url: new_subscription_url(:plan_id => plan.id),
      cancel_url: root_url
    )
  end

    def updatesubscription
      @user = current_user
      @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.subscription.stripe_customer_token)
      if @user.subscription.plan_id == 12
      @customer.update_subscription(:plan => "1", :prorate => true)
      current_user.subscription.update_attributes(:plan_id => 1)
      flash.alert = 'Your subscription has been changed to monthly!'
      redirect_to root_url
    elsif @user.subscription.plan_id == 1
      @customer.update_subscription(:plan => "12", :prorate => true)
      current_user.subscription.update_attributes(:plan_id => 12)
     current_user.save!
      flash.alert = 'Your subscription has been changed to annually!'
      redirect_to root_url
    end
     end

     def cancelsubscription
       @user = current_user
         @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.subscription.stripe_customer_token)
         @customer.cancel_subscription()
         current_user.subscription.update_attributes(:cancelled => 1)
         current_user.save!
         flash.alert = 'Your subscription has been cancelled successfully!'
         redirect_to root_url
       end

       def showcard
         @user = current_user
         Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.subscription.stripe_customer_token).cards.all()
       end

           def suspend
             @user = current_user
             @user.subscription.suspend_paypal
             current_user.subscription.update_attributes(:cancelled => 1)
               flash.alert = 'Billing has been suspended!'
                redirect_to root_url
           end

           def reactivate
             @user = current_user
             @user.subscription.reactivate_paypal
             current_user.subscription.update_attributes(:cancelled => nil)
               flash.alert = 'Billing has been activated!'
                redirect_to root_url
           end


               def edit_card
                 @user = current_user
               end

               def update_card
                 @user = current_user
                 card_info = {
                   name:    params[:name],
                   number:    params[:number],
                   exp_month: params[:date][:month],
                   exp_year:  params[:date][:year],
                   cvc:       params[:cvc]
                 }
                 if @user.subscription.update_card(@subscriber, card_info)
                   flash.alert = 'Saved. Your card information has been updated.'
                   redirect_to root_url
                 else
                   flash.alert = 'Stripe reported an error while updating your card. Please try again.'
                   redirect_to root_url
                 end
               end
end
```

routes:

```
  post "paypal/ipn" => "notifications#create"
```

Payment Notifications controller:

```
def index

  redirect_to root_url
end

   def create
     PaymentNotification.create!(:params => params, :status => params[:payment_status], :transaction_id => params[:txn_id])
     render :nothing => true
   end
 end
```

Notifications controller:

```
  def create
            query = params
            query[:cmd] = "_notify-validate"
            if(response.body == "VERIFIED")
                Rails.logger.debug params.inspect "Notification is valid"
            end
           end
    end
```

Comment: side note: be aware of the PayPal 'refund' hack(https://www.etsy.com/teams/7718/questions/discuss/12758905/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your routes.

It should be:

```
  match '/paypal/ipn' => 'notifications#create', :via => [:get, :post], :as => 'notifications_create'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [PayPal developer site](https://developer.paypal.com/) there is an IPN test tool. You can provide it your callback URL and send sample calls. You'll have to register first to use it.

Answer (score 0):

So you're only problem is getting the IPN's to trigger in your test account..??  When you use the Simulator does everything work as expected?

To get IPN working in the sandbox all you need to do is make sure it's enabled in your sandbox seller account profile.  You can login to your sandbox account at http://sandbox.paypal.com just like you would a live account. Once you're in there go into the profile and then into IPN settings so you can enable it and set the URL accordingly.

Comment: The issue is how should I define my IPN url so that I can provide PayPal sandbox a IPN.

Comment: That's what I just explained.

Comment: I understand how to enable/disable the IPN. I'm asking do I need to create a method in the controller that will create a IPN URL that I can test with? I am not sure at how to generate a IPN URL so I can use with Paypal.

Comment: You could build it any way you want to, really.  It's nothing more than a script of some sort that can be reached via a public URL (or at least opened up to PayPal's IP addresses).  IPN is essentially just a for POST, so you just need to setup a listener that can process this POST data accordingly.

Comment: Hi Cornelius, I wonder whether you need a tunnel. If it is the case, then try this: https://ngrok.com/ . If it does not work, please let me know.

Comment: The issue was setting the routes up. I had it incorrect, and the tunnel worked perfectly, thanks.